# Scrollspy does not work with ios devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I just finished my first website, its my portfolio website. Anyways on my navbar, I have my links that scroll to a certain section on my page. It works perfectly on desktop and my android devices(lg g4, nexus 7).

But when I try to to use it on my wifes iphone(tried it on ipod touch as well) it does not function at all. I tried using chrome on the ios as well instead of safari and its the same problem.(also another problem with ios, the home image only shows the very top(the clouds) and thats it which is odd as well, again only occurs with ios).

My javascript code I am using is below, but I also tried using smoothScroll as well(taking out the js script) and that wouldn't work either. The js will be below, also my CodePen will be too for you to test as well. Any help would be grateful thanks!

http://codepen.io/freefora11/pen/zrrGgM

```
    <script async>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').scrollspy({
  target: ".navbar",
  offset: 50
});

// Add smooth scrolling to all links inside a navbar
$("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {

  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash (#)
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area (the speed of the animation)
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function() {

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
});
});

    </script>
```